# One table/figure per page in LaTeX

Tags: floats, positioning

I am struggling with `figure`/`table` positioning in LaTeX. Basically, I'd like to have one `figure`/`table` per page. I found how to, but the problem is that LaTeX puts the `table`/`figure` in a single page, but the page before the figure page is not filled with text. So, basically I have a page filled for an half, a page with my `figure`/`table` and lastly a page filled normally with text. I'd like to have the two pages filled homogeneously with text. Is there any option that I'm missing?

I am using the package `float` with `p` option and a `\clearpage` at the end of each `figure`/`table`.

I hope I've been clear in my explanation.

Comment: I would say don't clearpage after each figure call, but rather invoke the figure with the [p] option to place it on a separate page.  My comment does not account for the use of the float package, though.  I'm not familiar with that.

Comment: There are a number of float placement parameters that LaTeX uses in order to decide whether the float can/should be placed where it's called. This is described in detail in [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764) and [Keeping tables/figures close to where they are mentioned](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2275/5764). I think you're particularly interested in setting `totalnumber` (default is 3; the maximum number of floats on a text (!) page).

Comment: Your `\clearpage` causes the unwanted blank fill. But you need it if you want the figure to appear on the next page. The solution is to defer the `\clearpage` until the point when the current page is filled with text, so it will not produce the undesired blank space. This can be achieved by putting `\afterpage{\clearpage}` right after the figure (`afterpage` package is required)

Answer (score 4):

I've found the solution..this works just fine for me

```
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.01}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.01}
\renewcommand{\bottomfraction}{0.01}
\renewcommand{\floatpagefraction}{0.01}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{1}
```

thanks everybody for any kind of help

Comment: If you run into emergency situations in which a manual adjust is required, you may find useful the `\afterpage{\clearpage}` trick I explained in a comment to your question.